# How can I implement IServiceProvider?

Tags: delphi, com, bho, delphi-xe7, urlmon

How can I implement `IServiceProvider` in the class which I inherit other interfaces from so their methods actually get called? Right now I always get `E_NOINTERFACE` back from `QueryInterface`.

```
    TPassthrough = class(TComObject, IInternetProtocolRoot, IInternetProtocolSink, IInternetProtocol, IServiceProvider)
    private
      FDefaultSink: IInternetProtocol;
      FProtSink: IInternetProtocolSink;
      FBindInfo: IInternetBindInfo;
    public
    { IServiceProvider }
    function QueryService(const rsid, iid: TGuid; out Obj): HResult; stdcall;

    { IInternetProtocolSink }
    function Switch(const ProtocolData: TProtocolData): HResult; stdcall;
    function ReportProgress(ulStatusCode: ULONG; szStatusText: LPCWSTR): HResult; stdcall;
    function ReportData(grfBSCF: DWORD; ulProgress, ulProgressMax: ULONG): HResult; stdcall;
    function ReportResult(hrResult: HResult; dwError: DWORD; szResult: LPCWSTR): HResult; stdcall;

    { IInternetProtocolRoot }
    function Start(szUrl: LPCWSTR; OIProtSink: IInternetProtocolSink; OIBindInfo: IInternetBindInfo; grfPI, dwReserved: DWORD): HResult; stdcall;
    function Continue(const ProtocolData: TProtocolData): HResult; overload; stdcall;
    function Abort(hrReason: HResult; dwOptions: DWORD): HResult; stdcall;
    function Terminate(dwOptions: DWORD): HResult; stdcall;
    function Suspend: HResult; stdcall;
    function Resume: HResult; stdcall;

    { IInternetProtocol }
    function Read(pv: Pointer; cb: ULONG; out cbRead: ULONG): HResult; stdcall;
    function Seek(dlibMove: LARGE_INTEGER; dwOrigin: DWORD; out libNewPosition: ULARGE_INTEGER): HResult; stdcall;
    function LockRequest(dwOptions: DWORD): HResult; stdcall;
    function UnlockRequest: HResult; stdcall;
    end;

...

function TPassthrough.Start(szUrl: LPCWSTR; OIProtSink: IInternetProtocolSink; OIBindInfo: IInternetBindInfo; grfPI, dwReserved: DWORD): HResult; stdcall;
begin
  if (FDefaultSink = nil) then
  OleCheck(CoCreateInstance(CLSID_HttpProtocol, nil, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IUnknown, FDefaultSink));

  FBindInfo := OIBindInfo;
  FProtSink := OIProtSink;

  if (Assigned(FDefaultSink)) then
    Result := (FDefaultSink as IInternetProtocolRoot).Start(szUrl, Self, Self, grfPI, dwReserved)
  else
    Result := E_NOTIMPL;
end; 

function TPassthrough.QueryService(const rsid, iid: TGuid; out Obj): HResult; stdcall;
begin
  Result := E_NOINTERFACE;
  Pointer(Obj) := nil;

  if Succeeded(QueryInterface(rsid, Obj)) and
    Assigned(Pointer(Obj))
  then
    Result := S_OK;
end;
```

Comment: Hard to see how `TPassthrough.QueryInterface` could fail to return the interface. Are you sure that `QI` is being called on the right object?

Comment: Who calls QueryService? Other part of you code or external code? Stupid question but are you sure rsid (iid) param of QueryService is equal to IID_IInternetProtocolRoot or IID_IInternetProtocolSink or IID_IInternetProtocol?

Comment: You've not shown the relevant code. I think we can assume that `QI` works. Either you are calling `QI` on the wrong object, or passing the wrong IID.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The purpose of `QueryService` is different from the purpose of `QueryInterface`.

`QueryService` should return a pointer to the object itself if it provides the requested service (through `rsid`), otherwise it should delegate to some other object, typically a container and with another `QueryService` call.

If no such service is found, it should return `E_NOTIMPL`.

The returned interface pointer will be of the requested type (through `iid`), so if the service is found, the object that implements the service is finally `QueryInterface`d.

If no such interface is implemented by the object, it should return `E_NOINTERFACE`.

It so happens that many service IDs (SID) are the same GUID as the typically implemented interface ID (IID), for instance, `SID_SInternetSecurityManager` and `IID_IInternetSecurityManager`.  Although this is a widely used convention, it is not a rule.  For instance, [you can ask for the `SID_SWebBrowserApp` service as a `IID_IWebBrowser2` interface pointer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257717).

So, analysing your [original code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28090884/800524):

```
function TPassthrough.QueryService(const rsid, iid: TGuid; out Obj): HResult; stdcall;
begin
  Result := E_NOINTERFACE;
  Pointer(Obj) := nil;

  if Succeeded(QueryInterface(rsid, Obj)) and
    Assigned(Pointer(Obj))
  then
    Result := S_OK;
end;
```

You're kind of just transforming `QueryService` into `QueryInterface` using a service ID (`rsid`), which is similar but not necessarily related to interface IDs (`iid`).  As such, if the two differ, the caller may get an incompatible interface pointer.

Then, the [changed code](http://pastebin.com/NiAcxruP):

```
function TMonitor.QueryService(const rsid, iid: TGuid; out Obj): HResult; stdcall;
begin
  Result := E_NOINTERFACE;
  Pointer(Obj) := nil;

  if Succeeded(QueryInterface(iid, Obj)) and
    Assigned(Pointer(Obj))
  then
    Result := S_OK;
end;
```

This is saying that the object implements **every** imaginable service, so it merely delegates to `QueryInterface`, but at least correctly with `iid`.

This is what you should do:

```
function TMonitor.QueryService(const rsid, iid: TGuid; out Obj): HResult; stdcall;
begin
  if Not Assigned(@Obj) then
  begin
    Result := E_POINTER;
    Exit;
  end;

  Pointer(Obj) := nil;
  Result := E_NOTIMPL;

  if Assigned(FServiceProvider) then
    Result := FServiceProvider.QueryService(rsid, iid, Obj);
end;
```

Should you want to provide your own services, you can optionally use the following code:

```
function TMonitor.QueryService(const rsid, iid: TGuid; out Obj): HResult; stdcall;
begin
  if Not Assigned(@Obj) then
  begin
    Result := E_POINTER;
    Exit;
  end;

  Pointer(Obj) := nil;
  Result := E_NOTIMPL;

  if IsEqualGUID(rsid, SID_SOverrideService1) or
     IsEqualGUID(rsid, SID_SOverrideService2)
  then
    Result := QueryInterface(iid, Obj);

  if Result = E_NOTIMPL and
     Assigned(FServiceProvider)
  then
    Result := FServiceProvider.QueryService(rsid, iid, Obj);

  if Result = E_NOTIMPL and
     (IsEqualGUID(rsid, SID_SFallbackService1) or
      IsEqualGUID(rsid, SID_SFallbackService2))
  then
    Result := QueryInterface(iid, Obj);
end;
```

Where `SID_OverrideServiceN` are the service IDs you want to override and `SID_FallbackServiceN` are the service IDs you want to fallback to.  Note that I changed `Succeeded(Result)` to `Result <> E_NOTIMPL`, because I don't want to keep looking for services if one was actually found but some other error happened, e.g. the requested interface was not implemented (`E_NOINTERFACE`).

Comment: I think  you should add an `AddRef` on Obj without it can cause refcounting issues.

Answer (score 3):

You're querying for the service ID (rsid), not interface ID (iid).